# How to embed Soundcloud tracks

Tags: api, embed, soundcloud

As the tilt suggests, Im trying to figure out how to embed a soundcloud file, and how can i change which sound is embed easily..

I have a site that at the moment, lets users write a story then attach an image or video to it. for the video, i use vimeo and youtube. All the user does is copy and past the url for the video and then i have a php script that does the rest....

I need the same for Soundcloud...

Please Help, as this is the last hurdle i need to cross to finish my project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On each track on SoundCloud there is a 'Share' link in the top left.  Clicking it reveals a embed code which you can use to embed it on a different site.  If you want you can even customize how it looks.  There is some more information available on their [widgets page](http://soundcloud.com/pages/widgets).

You could also use a service like [embed.ly](http://api.embed.ly/) that would help abstract the embeding of the data for all of your objects.

Changing the tracks on the fly would have to be done using JavaScript.